# How to tidy a deeply nested json-File in R?

Tags: r, json, unnest

There is a json-File I would like to analyze:
https://dam-api.bfs.admin.ch/hub/api/dam/assets/21364129/master

It has data about four different referendums (all from the same date), all the results for each region (kanton) and on community-level (gemeinde). I tried to make a tidy df out of this, but I don't even understand the exact syntax of the unnest-command (cols?).

After a lot of try and error, I can get the data for a specific kanton, for example like this:
flatten(df$schweiz$vorlagen$kantone[[4]]$gemeinden[[13]])

But there must be some way to get this data for all 26 cantons, and of course with the information to which one of the four referendum the data belongs. I guess that some tools from the purrr-package might be helpful, but all the tutorials i read so far have been a mistery to me.

So, in short: Is there a way to get this file tidy without hours of manual work?

Answer (score 2):

Converting such a large and complex structure into a data frame requires specific knowledge of what you want your final output to be, and you really need to tailor your code to do it. In this case, I assume you want a list containing 4 data frames (one for each referendum), where each row gives the kantone, the gemeinden, and the various fields indicating the result from each gemeinden. This is complex, but something like the following should work:

```r
url <- "https://dam-api.bfs.admin.ch/hub/api/dam/assets/21364129/master"

json <- jsonlite::read_json(url)

result <- lapply(json$schweiz$vorlagen, function(x) {
  dplyr::as_tibble(do.call(rbind, lapply(x$kantone, function(y) {
    k <- y$geoLevelname
    do.call(rbind, lapply(y$gemeinden, function(z) {
      cbind(data.frame(kantone = k, gemeinden = z$geoLevelname),
            as.data.frame(z$resultat))
    }))
  })))
})
```

So your result looks like this:

```
result
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2,156 x 10
#>    kantone gemeinden          gebietAusgezaeh~ jaStimmenInProz~ jaStimmenAbsolut
#>    <chr>   <chr>              <lgl>                       <dbl>            <int>
#>  1 Zürich  Aeugst am Albis    TRUE                         25.4              194
#>  2 Zürich  Affoltern am Albis TRUE                         20.4              661
#>  3 Zürich  Bonstetten         TRUE                         17.9              345
#>  4 Zürich  Hausen am Albis    TRUE                         20.9              286
#>  5 Zürich  Hedingen           TRUE                         19.3              269
#>  6 Zürich  Kappel am Albis    TRUE                         24.1               93
#>  7 Zürich  Knonau             TRUE                         21.6              161
#>  8 Zürich  Maschwanden        TRUE                         21.1               49
#>  9 Zürich  Mettmenstetten     TRUE                         19.3              368
#> 10 Zürich  Obfelden           TRUE                         21.5              325
#> # ... with 2,146 more rows, and 5 more variables: neinStimmenAbsolut <int>,
#> #   stimmbeteiligungInProzent <dbl>, eingelegteStimmzettel <int>,
#> #   anzahlStimmberechtigte <int>, gueltigeStimmen <int>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2,156 x 10
#>    kantone gemeinden          gebietAusgezaeh~ jaStimmenInProz~ jaStimmenAbsolut
#>    <chr>   <chr>              <lgl>                       <dbl>            <int>
#>  1 Zürich  Aeugst am Albis    TRUE                         60.3              470
#>  2 Zürich  Affoltern am Albis TRUE                         61.2             2014
#>  3 Zürich  Bonstetten         TRUE                         59.8             1166
#>  4 Zürich  Hausen am Albis    TRUE                         57.7              796
#>  5 Zürich  Hedingen           TRUE                         58.5              826
#>  6 Zürich  Kappel am Albis    TRUE                         49.6              192
#>  7 Zürich  Knonau             TRUE                         56.8              431
#>  8 Zürich  Maschwanden        TRUE                         52.6              123
#>  9 Zürich  Mettmenstetten     TRUE                         58.3             1119
#> 10 Zürich  Obfelden           TRUE                         57.2              868
#> # ... with 2,146 more rows, and 5 more variables: neinStimmenAbsolut <int>,
#> #   stimmbeteiligungInProzent <dbl>, eingelegteStimmzettel <int>,
#> #   anzahlStimmberechtigte <int>, gueltigeStimmen <int>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2,156 x 10
#>    kantone gemeinden          gebietAusgezaeh~ jaStimmenInProz~ jaStimmenAbsolut
#>    <chr>   <chr>              <lgl>                       <dbl>            <int>
#>  1 Zürich  Aeugst am Albis    TRUE                         39.6              301
#>  2 Zürich  Affoltern am Albis TRUE                         35.7             1150
#>  3 Zürich  Bonstetten         TRUE                         36.2              697
#>  4 Zürich  Hausen am Albis    TRUE                         39.5              531
#>  5 Zürich  Hedingen           TRUE                         37.1              509
#>  6 Zürich  Kappel am Albis    TRUE                         42.9              162
#>  7 Zürich  Knonau             TRUE                         36.7              273
#>  8 Zürich  Maschwanden        TRUE                         37.1               86
#>  9 Zürich  Mettmenstetten     TRUE                         39.2              742
#> 10 Zürich  Obfelden           TRUE                         34.4              513
#> # ... with 2,146 more rows, and 5 more variables: neinStimmenAbsolut <int>,
#> #   stimmbeteiligungInProzent <dbl>, eingelegteStimmzettel <int>,
#> #   anzahlStimmberechtigte <int>, gueltigeStimmen <int>
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 2,156 x 10
#>    kantone gemeinden          gebietAusgezaeh~ jaStimmenInProz~ jaStimmenAbsolut
#>    <chr>   <chr>              <lgl>                       <dbl>            <int>
#>  1 Zürich  Aeugst am Albis    TRUE                         39.0              300
#>  2 Zürich  Affoltern am Albis TRUE                         40.8             1321
#>  3 Zürich  Bonstetten         TRUE                         42.8              826
#>  4 Zürich  Hausen am Albis    TRUE                         41.6              570
#>  5 Zürich  Hedingen           TRUE                         44.1              615
#>  6 Zürich  Kappel am Albis    TRUE                         35.5              136
#>  7 Zürich  Knonau             TRUE                         38.6              290
#>  8 Zürich  Maschwanden        TRUE                         42.7              100
#>  9 Zürich  Mettmenstetten     TRUE                         39.6              757
#> 10 Zürich  Obfelden           TRUE                         40.5              610
#> # ... with 2,146 more rows, and 5 more variables: neinStimmenAbsolut <int>,
#> #   stimmbeteiligungInProzent <dbl>, eingelegteStimmzettel <int>,
#> #   anzahlStimmberechtigte <int>, gueltigeStimmen <int>
```

If you want them all in one big data frame, you can add a number or name column to indicate which referendum you are referring to, then bind all the data frames together.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Wow, thank you, I should really investigate the lapply-function deeper. So there is no point in using the purrr-tools here?

Comment: You can use `purrr` tools if you like, but ultimately you will find that you still need to pick out the useful elements in the list and tell R how to arrange them. There is no "magic" solution to a problem like this one.

Comment: I was hoping that purrr-code might be easier to read. Could you please elaborate how the funtion(x) and y are working here? Do they just deliver the first part of the path?